# If statement in Loop in Grid view

Tags: vb.net, loops, gridview, for-loop

I am trying to check the dates in Cell (3) of each row. I am only able to get the date if the first `If` condition is true, the rest of the cells are appearing blank. The code is as follows.

```
        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            If Not IsDBNull(dr("B1Week").ToString) Then
                e.Row.Cells(3).Text = dr("B1week").ToString
                e.Row.Cells(3).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue

            ElseIf DD2 <= Now Then
                e.Row.Cells(3).Text = e.Row.Cells(3).Text & " - OVERDUE"
                e.Row.Cells(3).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red

            ElseIf DD2 <= Now.AddDays(7) Then
                e.Row.Cells(3).Text = e.Row.Cells(3).Text & " - DUE "
                e.Row.Cells(3).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green

            End If

        Next row
```

I want each cell 3 in each row to be checked and the value assigned. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your For Each loop you need to use the row variable:

```
    For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
        If Not IsDBNull(dr("B1Week").ToString) Then
            row.Cells(3).Text = dr("B1week").ToString
            row.Cells(3).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue

        ElseIf DD2 <= Now Then
            row.Cells(3).Text = e.Row.Cells(3).Text & " - OVERDUE"
            row.Cells(3).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red

        ElseIf DD2 <= Now.AddDays(7) Then
            row.Cells(3).Text = e.Row.Cells(3).Text & " - DUE "
            row.Cells(3).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green

        End If

    Next row
```

Comment: Could please tell me how to do it because presently the first if condition if true is being displayed. where the first if is false the cells are appearing blank.

Comment: Have you looked at the code above? I already edited it to change e.Row.Cells(3) to row.Cells(3)...